# How to compare the dateTime store in firestore with the current dateTime?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the option to let the user choose the due date via DatePickerDialog. Then, another option choose the time via TimePickerDialog. Both of the date and time will store into Firestore. So, how should I do to compare them with the current date and time?

I am using the query below. And the date and time store in Firestore like this **19/5/2020 17:34**

```
public class StudentHomework extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
FirebaseFirestore objectFirebaseFirestore;
CollectionReference userRef;
private FirestoreRecyclerAdapter <HomeworkModel, HomeworkViewHolder> adapter;
String cid;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_student_homework );

    objectFirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    cid = intent.getStringExtra( "classId" );


    recyclerView = findViewById( R.id.recycler_view1 );
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize( false );
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager( this ) );

    userRef = objectFirebaseFirestore.collection( "homework" );

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    Timestamp timestamp1 = new Timestamp( c.getTimeInMillis() );
    Date date = new Date(timestamp1.getTime());

    Toast.makeText( StudentHomework.this, "Current Date: " + date, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

    Query query = userRef.whereEqualTo( "classId", cid ).whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo( "due_date_time", date ).orderBy( "due_date_time", Query.Direction.ASCENDING );

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions options1 = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<HomeworkModel>().setQuery( query, HomeworkModel.class ).build();

    adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<HomeworkModel, HomeworkViewHolder>( options1 ) {

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final HomeworkViewHolder homeworkViewHolder, final int position, @NonNull final HomeworkModel homeworkModel) {

            homeworkViewHolder.title.setText( homeworkModel.getTitle() );

        }
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public HomeworkViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from( parent.getContext() ).inflate( R.layout.list_homework, parent, false );
            return new HomeworkViewHolder( v );
        }
    };

    recyclerView.setAdapter( adapter );
}

private class HomeworkViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View view;
    TextView title;
    TextView due_date;

    public HomeworkViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super( itemView );
        view = itemView;
        title = itemView.findViewById( R.id.homerwork_title );
        due_date = itemView.findViewById( R.id.due_date1 );
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    StudentHomework.this.finish();
}
}
```

But I can't retrieve anything.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried the query stated in the question there

Answer (score 0):

Does your date and time stored on Firestore as String?

**You should use Time stamp.**

Save the time in HashMap (For example) as TimeStamp then update/set it to the cloud.

```
itemHashMap.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
// Now update to the cloud
```

Query like this:

```
Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().
                collection("collection").document("document")
                .collection("collection")
                .orderBy("timestamp");
```

Comment: yes, I stored it as String in Firestore. Because I get the 19/5/2020 from datePickerDialog and 17:34 from timePickerDialog. And then I concatenate them as String to store in Firestore. Then I want it to compare with the current date and time, if it is exceed, the data will not be displayed.

Comment: I have made it as Timestamp in Firestore and comparing them again. I still have no items displayed.

Comment: It's hard to know from your code whats went wrong there.
There could be several reasons. Maybe there are simply no results for this query.
Did you try to first query- "whereEqualTo()", see if there are any results for this and only then adding the second conditioning-  "whereLessThanOrEqualTo( )"?

Comment: I have checked there are results for the query. But when I added whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo(), no results pop out. I don't know what happened. I have updated the code in the question